# Broadleaf or apache Ofbiz

Tags: java, content-management-system, e-commerce

Which ecommerce platform is better in JAVA Broadleaf or apache ofbiz. If there are any better than these two please suggest..

Comment: Instead of Ofbiz, I'd recommend to take a look at [Opentaps](http://www.opentaps.org/), which is based on Ofbiz, but provides a lot of basic functionality. But you should review the FAQ on what kind of questions are welcome here, as this doesn't really qualify itself as one!

Answer (score 3):

I work for Broadleaf Commerce.  One of the key differences is the stack.    Broadleaf leverages the Spring framework (e.g. Spring Security, Spring-MVC, and core Spring) along with JPA/Hibernate as the primary underlying architecture.

Comment: AFAIK, newer Ofbiz (and Opentaps) releases use Hibernate too (besides their Geronimo based persistence).

Comment: @polster Which framework does apache ofbiz use. Currently i am working on struts-hibernate framework, so is there any ecommerce platform which uses struts-hibernate framework.

Answer (score 0):

OfBiz is a popular eCommerce tool designed with all the integrations for Supply Chain Management or ERP based solution. I think broad leaf is a basic eCommerce tool,  need to be integrated with all the SCM solutions, ofcouse it is easy to integrate with other tools.  DataFile tool of ofBiz is superior for data import and export operations.

Answer (score -2):

There is one company who has completed a benchmark test on some popular Open Source ecommerce platforms, including themselves along with Broadleaf, and Apache OfBiz. I’d say it’s worth checking out. The stats produced are very interesting! Anyways here is the link, and their product is Avetti Commerce: http://www.avetticommerce.com/ecommerce-performance-benchmarking

Comment: The above link gives a false representation of Broadleaf (and probably the other frameworks as well).    See Broadleaf Commerce.com for a free scalability report.    Performance testing can be very subjective .    Broadleaf powers the eCommerce sites for several billion dollar companies and is designed to scale and perform.

Comment: avetti is not open source